# Json not working with HttpPost probably around setEntity

Tags: android, json, entity, http-post

I am using this code to send this to my php file.
The file looks what is coming like this.

```
file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" . print_r($_GET, true));
```

I am sending the json like this:

```
public void postData(String url,JSONObject json) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String object = "?data=" +json.toString();
    System.out.println("object:" + object);
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url.toString());
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        System.out.println("url:" + url.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(object); 
        System.out.println("json:" + json.toString());

        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httppost.setEntity(se); 

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String temp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println("response:" + response);

        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Statuscode " + statusCode);

        if(statusCode==200) {
            Toast.makeText(LbsGeocodingActivity.this, "Verstuurd",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(statusCode!=200) {
            Toast.makeText(this, statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        /* try {
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Toast.makeText(this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

The log files are this:

```
01-08 09:36:00.278: I/System.out(1124): object:?data={"id":"69403","timestamp":"08-01-2013 09:36:00","longitude":"-122.084095","latitude":"37.422005"}
01-08 09:36:00.298: I/System.out(1124): json:{"id":"69403","timestamp":"08-01-2013 09:36:00","longitude":"-122.084095","latitude":"37.422005"}
01-08 09:36:01.038: I/System.out(1124): response:org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@412d1b38
01-08 09:36:01.038: I/System.out(1124): Statuscode 200
```

i left out the url for security reasons..

But i am getting an empty file in dump.txt

```
POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
)
```

**EDIT**

Something is wrong with the setEntity(or somewhere around there), because when i already paste ?data= in the url i get this from the PHP file:

```
POST: 
Array
(
)



 GET: 
Array
(
    [data] => 
)
```

Answer (score 10):

the way I send JSON with my `DefaultHttpClient` in my app work perfectly:

```
public static HttpUriRequest createPostForJSONObject(
        JSONObject params, String url) {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setEntity(createStringEntity(params));
    return post;
}

private static HttpEntity createStringEntity(JSONObject params) {
    StringEntity se = null;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(params.toString(), "UTF-8");
        se.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create StringEntity", e);
        exception = e;
    }
    return se;
}
```

in order to run this request in your code all you need to do is this:

```
public void postData(String url,JSONObject json) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
          HttpPost post = createPostForJSONObject(json, url);
          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
          // DO YOUR THING
    } catch Exception {
         // HANDLE EXCEPTION
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i am going to test it immediately

Comment: i am facing a little problem. How do i call this function requestNewVideoMessageWithThreadId from my code?

Comment: there's no method in here that's sending the httppost

Comment: all you need to do for sending is call `defaultHttpClent.execute(request)`

Comment: Wehre do i need to send that? in a new function or exactely after: "return se;"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22378/discussion-between-babboe-and-thepoosh)

Comment: Shouldn't createPostForJSONObject return HttpPost? I changed it but it's not working for me.