# HttpPost request does not send correct JSON data

Tags: java, json, web-services, post

I am currently trying to use the API by following the instructions of [fliptop](https://developer.fliptop.com/documentation).
The description of the api specifies that it has to use json input, Hence, I make the json object and convert it to string myself. However, when I try to use the **find_contact** api, the http response gets

**{"param":500}**

instead of correct data like

**{
 "account": {
  "site_key": "...",
  "seat_id": "...",
  "org_id": "",
  "license": {
...
}**.

I try to do some tests on documentation website(click any of advanced api and you will see it) by sending request with **incorrect input**, and it gives me the same response body **{"param":500}**. Hence, I think there might be something wrong with my request entity.

Here is my code. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Test {

    // Generate json string
    // {"contacts": [ { "email": "doug@fliptop.com", "title":"CEO", "company":"Fliptop", "address":"San Francisco"} ] }
    public static String jsonString() {
        JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
        obj1.put("email", "doug@fliptop.com");
        obj1.put("title", "CEO");
        obj1.put("company", "Fliptop");
        obj1.put("address", "San Francisco");
        JSONArray list1 = new JSONArray();
        list1.add(obj1);
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
        obj2.put("contacts", list1);
        System.out.println(obj2.toJSONString());
        return obj2.toJSONString();
    }

    public static void find_contact() {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
                    //you will need api key here!!
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://api.fliptop.com/s2/v1/find_contact?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            StringEntity params = new StringEntity(jsonString(),"UTF-8");
            params.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            request.setEntity(params);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String result = "";
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                result += line;
            }
            System.out.println(result);
            rd.close();
            System.out.println("status:" + response.getStatusLine());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        find_contact();
    }
}
```

**Update:**

I follow Dave's suggestion and check the request by **WireShark**. The request is showed as a **POST** request, and the data is text/plain with the following contents

**json={"contacts": [ { "email": "doug@fliptop.com", "title":"CEO", "company":"Fliptop", "address":"San Francisco"} ] }** .

I'm not a network expert, but the request seems fine to me. Still, I confused about what's going on...

Comment: Did you check the wire to see what you're actually sending?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to say... I do try to read the entity by putting it back to a InputStreamReader and  then BufferedReader. The string of entity itself is correct.

Comment: I'm saying "check your assumptions regarding what's actually being sent to their server by checking the request being made".

Comment: I do use the correct api key in my code. I don't put my api key in this demo code if that is what you're suggesting. Otherwise, I still have no idea what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: I'm trying to tell you to examine the actual request being made by checking what's actually being sent over the network; Debugging 101.

Comment: Ok, I try to capture the request by wire shark. The request is a POST request, and the data is text-plain **json={"contacts": [ { "email": "doug@fliptop.com", "title":"CEO", "company":"Fliptop", "address":"San Francisco"} ] }**. I am not an expert of network session, but it seems fine to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059278/how-to-post-json-request-using-apache-httpclient-3-1

Comment: @DaveNewton The api in the link is way too old, I cannot even find the apache httpclient 3.1 to try it. I found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119410/json-not-working-with-httppost-probably-around-setentity and made some changes. However, it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for a few more hours, I discover the cause of my issue by examining details of the post request from chrome. You can see the **Content-Type** is actually **"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"**, and that's why I keep failing. By changing my Content-Type, everything works fine.

[image]

Here are my codes, you can use the URL or the appache httpclient, they both work fine.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://api.fliptop.com/s2/v1/find_contact?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    writer.write(data);  // data = "json={\"contact\": { \"email\": \"robbie@fliptop.com\"}}"
    writer.close();

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {        
        BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), UTF_8));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line;
        }       
    }
```